# GWT: UI doesn't load until window is resized

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, user-interface, google-maps-api-3

I know that GWT no longer support quirks mode. Therefore, developers are discouraged to use RootPanel, DockPanel, etc. In implementing my app using a RootLayoutPanel and DockLayoutPanel, I am finding that the UI does not load until the browser window is resized.

To be clear, I run my app in Development Mode and refresh my browser (Google Chrome). Nothing appears in my browser although everything seems to have loaded fine according to my Eclipse console. Once I resize my browser window, all my content loads just fine.

Although I insert a MapWidget into my DockLayoutPanel, it doesn't seem like MapWidget is the culprit since removing the line "panel.add(mapWidget)" still has the same result. What could I be missing?

Below is the code from my main class. The HTML code has been omitted for brevity. In my actual code, I only put text and style in there.

```
public class MyApp implements EntryPoint {

    private MapWidget mapWidget;

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        loadMapWidget();
    }

    private void loadMapWidget() {

        // Does device have location tracking?
        boolean sensor = false;

        // Load proper map libraries
        ArrayList<LoadLibrary> loadLibraries = new ArrayList<LoadApi.LoadLibrary>();

        // Configure runnable
        Runnable onLoad = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Center on Vancouver
                LatLng center = LatLng.newInstance(49.261226, -123.1139268);

                // Configure Map Widget options
                MapOptions mapOptions = MapOptions.newInstance();
                mapOptions.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
                mapOptions.setCenter(center);
                mapOptions.setZoom(14);

                // Instantiate and configure Map Widget
                mapWidget = new MapWidget(mapOptions);

                // Configure Marker options
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = MarkerOptions.newInstance();
                markerOptions.setPosition(LatLng.newInstance(49.261226, -123.1139268));

                // Create Marker
                final Marker marker = Marker.newInstance(markerOptions);
                marker.setMap(mapWidget);

                plotMapWidgetOntoPanel();
            }

        };

        LoadApi.go(onLoad, loadLibraries, sensor);
    }

    private void plotMapWidgetOntoPanel() {
        DockLayoutPanel panel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
        panel.addEast(new HTML("..."), 20);
        panel.addNorth(new HTML("..."), 1.5);
        panel.addSouth(new HTML("..."), .5);
        panel.add(mapWidget);
        mapWidget.triggerResize();
        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `panel.forceLayout` after the `RootLayoutPanel.get().add(panel)` statement? I've found that this works in some cases.

Comment: I just tried it but unfortunately the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

in order to use gwt MapWidget you have to set its size absolutely

for example : `mapwidget.setSize("600px","600px")`

if you want to set its size dynamically you must set its size according its parent widget size in this manner :

```
mapwidget.setSize(mapwidget.getParent().getElement().getStyle().getWidth(),
                    mapwidget.getParent().getElement().getStyle().getHeight());
```

I hope this solution help you;

Comment: No luck unfortunately. Like I said, it doesn't look like the MapWidget is the culprit. Whether MapWidget is given a static size or not, the page requires resizing to load.